# Generate dinamically blocks on Filament 2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filament, filamentphp

I want to create somehow dinamicaly content blocks on how many languages i have, but the problem is this way, how i try it, it generates same block 4 time per language tab, and i want to generate it just 1 time per each language tab. I want to create a paragraph, but that paragraph should be generated to all tabs 1 time. :

On that image i described all what i tried:

````
        $tabs = [];
        $lang = [];
        foreach ($languages as $key => $language) {
            if ($key < $languages->count()) {
                if (!array_key_exists($language->id, $lang)) {
                    $lang = array_merge($lang, [
                        $language->id]);
                    \Log::info('Processing language: ' . $language->id);
                    // Check if blocks for the current language have already been created
                    if (!isset($languageBlocks[$language->id])) {
                        // If not, create blocks and store them in the array
                        $languageBlocks[$language->id] = [
                            'paragraph' => self::makeParagraphBlock($language),
                            'button_name' => self::makeButtonBlock($language),
                            'image' => self::makeImageBlock($language),
                            'elements_number' => self::makeElementsNumberBlock($language),
                        ];
                    }

                    // Use the stored blocks for the current language
                    $blocks = $languageBlocks[$language->id];

                    $tabs = array_merge($tabs, [
                        Forms\Components\Tabs\Tab::make(__($language->name[$language->id]->text))->schema([
                            Forms\Components\Builder::make('content')
                                ->label('Tartalom')
                                ->collapsible()
                                ->schema($blocks),
                        ])
                    ]);
                }
            } else {
                break;
            }

        }

        return $form->schema([
            Forms\Components\Card::make()
                ->schema([
                    Forms\Components\TextInput::make('id')->hidden(),
                    Forms\Components\Card::make()
                        ->schema([
                            Forms\Components\TextInput::make('content_blocks')->label('Blok név'),
                        ]),
                    Forms\Components\Tabs::make('Localization')->tabs($tabs),
                ]),
        ]);```
````

Comment: [Don't post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: Can you post your sample input data (tabs) as array or json ?